# PublishRequest<T> IBus extension equivalent in v5.x

Tags: masstransit

With v5 PublishRequest extension was removed from the IBus interface.

We used the callback to handle multiple response types that could be returned from the consumer ( Faults, Validations, actual responses, etc )

What is the equivalent way of publishing a message and wiring up multiple response types ?

```
// Request/Response contracts, may also return validation failure or fault contract
Request<TMessage> request = await bus.PublishRequest<TMessage>( msg, context => {
    context.Handle<TResponse>( value => ... );
    context.Handle<TValidation>( value => ... );
    context.Handle<Fault>( value => ... );

    context.CorrelationId = ...
    context.Headers.Set( ... );
});

await request.Task;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new syntax, which is much cleaner overall.

```
var client = Bus.CreateRequestClient<RegisterMember>();

var (registered, existing) = 
    await client.GetResponse<MemberRegistered, ExistingMemberFound>(
        new RegisterMember() {MemberId = "Johnny5"});
```

This will return either of the two responses, and if a fault occurs, either will throw the faulted request exception.

You can also use a request handle to add headers, etc.

```
var client = Bus.CreateRequestClient<RegisterMember>();

var request = client.Create(new RegisterMember()
    {MemberId = "Johnny5"});

// the request is also the send pipe configurator, so...
request.UseExecute(context => context.CorrelationId = someId);

var (registered, existing) = 
    await request.GetResponse<MemberRegistered, ExistingMemberFound>();
```

You can see a working test case in the future tests:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Futures.Tests/Request_Specs.cs#L170

Comment: Thanks... question on the creation of the client object... should we create that as late as possible, or inject using a factory function per operation, or can we create, cache, and reuse ?

Comment: Where do request headers get set.  I can't find any method, or extension, that exposes any equivalent of context.Headers.Set

Comment: If you're within a consumer, create it using the `ConsumeContext` of that consumer, using the client factory. To add headers, I'll edit the above.